# C++ Logical error [N-Queen]

Tags: c++

this is my 1st time posting a question here so please go easy on me .

I recently came across the n-queen / 8 queen problem and found it interesting enough to try it

I made a basic code for the problem , but its not giving out any output . When I tried to debug it , it showed that the flow was not going beyond a certain point and would return to its parent function for further iterations .

As such after putting some time on it , I seem to be unable to understand the problem and hence , decided to ask for help .

Also , it seems that I need to define the size of array in function header for 2-D /3-D arrays and so on .....

P.S I am a student , so I might get some concepts wrong. Sorry if some of them are too stupid .

Here's the code :

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define RED -1
#define BLACK 0
#define OCCUPIED 1

//RED = Cell attackable by queen(s)
//BLACK = Cell safe from attack and hence a piece may be placed there
//OCCUPIED = Cell where a queen resides


void display(int,int[20][20]);
void nqueen(int,int[20][20],int=0);

int main()
{
    //clrscr();
    int n,board[20][20];
    cout<<"Enter value of n:";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
            board[i][j]=BLACK; //Initializing the board to black

    nqueen(n,board); //Calling function
    return 0;
}


void display(int n,int board[20][20])  //Gives an error if i dont define size of board
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
            if(board[i][j]==OCCUPIED)
                cout<<"O";
            else
                cout<<"X";

        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\nPress 0 to exit....";    //Allows the program ot be terminated mid-way
    int ch;
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch==0)
        exit(1);
    //clrscr();
}

//Displays all the boards contents O = Occupied while X = Not occupied

void nqueen(int n,int board[20][20],int row) //row is given a default value 0
{
    if(row==n)              //End Statement
    {
        display(n,board);
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)          //Looping within row's columns to check for BLACK cells
        if(board[row][i]==BLACK)  //condition
        {

            //-------Puts attack (RED) on the board------
            for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
                board[j][i]=RED; //all cells in column turned red . Not done for row so as to allow further ilteation .
            for(int k=0;(k+row)<n&&(k+i)<n;++k)
                board[row+k][i+k]=RED; //This reds out the diagonal right cells. Left upper rows unaltered as its too much of a useless bother
            for(int k=0;(k+row)<n&&(i-k)>=0;++k)
                                    board[row+k][i-k]=RED; //This reds out the diagonal left cells. Left upper rows unaltered as its too much of a useless bother

            //------Done putting reds-----------
            board[row][i]=OCCUPIED; //Placed queen on cell
            nqueen(n,board,row+1);//Recursion continues
            board[row][i]=BLACK; //Returns back to black for further iltertions
         }
}
```

//------------------------------------------------

I am thankful for the advice , I still cant believe I did such a stupid mistake on that loop , I changed the left cell redding to the following :

```
    for(int k=0;(k+row)<n&&(i-k)>=0;++k)
                     board[row+k][i-k]=RED; //This reds out the diagonal left cells. Left upper rows unaltered as its too much of a useless bother
```

I had originally forgotten to put it in and so didn't get to check it out later on , sorry .

Anyways , after changing it to work properly , I found that it does give me an output ,but only for n=5 . Next thing , its only giving me 1 output even though there are 2 outputs [if I am correct that satisfy the n=5 condition] . For the rest of the inputs , its still doing the same

---

As for the compiler , I am currently using code blocks , but I had debugged it in Turbo. 
I realize that Turbo has some problems , so I had put in the last couple of changes in Code Blocks.

As for Visual Studio , I cant use it . Its a paid software and since this is just a hobby , my parents will kill me for spending money on it .

The flow as such was terminating on i=2 for n=5 and i=4 for n=7 and so on . 
The flow for n=5 seems to be now disrupting after 1st go through while the rest are still broken

Comment: *"...the flow was not going beyond a certain point..."* Ok. I'll bite.  And that point was/is... ? Have you stepped through this with a debugger yet?

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem, and you seem to be new to C++. Here's a tip: make `board` into a proper class. I.e. implement a constructor for an empty board, and a copy constructor. The ability to make a copy greatly simplifies backtracking.

Comment: May I inquire how a copy constructor would help in this situation??

Comment: _My_ recommendation is sticking a ton of `assert`s inside and around your loops to check the pre-conditions and post-conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I *strongly* advise reading [Program Development By Stepwise Refinement](http://sunnyday.mit.edu/16.355/wirth-refinement.html). As a bonus, the primary sample of Mr. Wirth's article is the 8-queens problem, and many of the concepts hold true today, some 42 years after the paper was first published.

Regarding your specific code, one thing that immediately pops out is the following:

```
for(int k=(row>i?row:i);(row-k)>=0&&(i-k)>=0;--k)
    board[row-k][i-k]=RED;
```

what happens when this executed on the *first* iteration of both the `i` and `row` loops?  Well,

```
int k=(row>i?row:i);
```

`k` will be zero (0). Next, the test condition will hold because...

```
(row-k)>=0 && (i-k)>=0;
```

Since all three values (`row`, `i`, and `k`) are all zero (0) this equates to :

```
(0-0)>=0 && (0-0)>=0
```

which is certainly true.. This takes us to the loop body, a single statement:

```
board[row-k][i-k]=RED;
```

Doesn't do much except set the space at `[0][0]` to RED. But now, look what happens in the increment-step of the for-loop:

```
--k
```

now k is (-1), thus the condition expression is

```
(0-(-1))>=0 && (0-(-1))>=0
```

**which is still true**, since `1>=0 && 1>=0` holds. Therefore, we go back to the body of the loop and...

```
board[0-(-1)][i-(-1)]=RED;
```

which is simply...

```
board[1][1]=RED;
```

Once again, we hit the increment clause of the for-loop, which assigns (-2) to `k`. The condition clause still holds:

```
(0-(-2))>=0 && (0-(-2))>=0
```

So yet again, we're back to the for-body and eventually...

```
board[2][2]=RED;
```

This continues until `--k` sufficiently causes your `board[][]` indexes to walk well-past the end of your array limits and into the land of **undefined behavior**.

I suggest you reexamine your algorithm implementation for correctness.

Comment: @user2695442 That would be the "step" part of "stepwise refinement"

Comment: Was almost expecting to see "Stepwise Refinement" as your SO username when I hit the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit LOL. There was a lot of it going on when I was dissecting this bug, I assure you =P. I am a huge Nick W. fan though, if it wasn't already obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to break in your third `for` loop - when the value of `k` is `-43`. Is it supposed to be like that?

[image]

I recommend debugging your code step by step, using a good debugging tool, like Visual Studio. For example, this is what your `board` looks like when you call your `nqueen()` function:

[image]

This seems wrong, as well as many other things; Personally I would start it from scratch and make sure every single part of the algorithm works perfectly. Your code is now large and not very maintainable, that's why you're having troubles finding errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int k=(row>i?row:i); (row-k)>=0 && (row-k)<n && (i-k)>=0 && (i-k)<n;--k)
            board[row-k][i-k]=RED;
```

Init your table first, i.e.:

```
#define UNASIGNED_FIELD 2
for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
    for(int j=0;j<20;++j)
        board[i][j]=UNASIGNED_FIELD;
```

BTW this is not good piece of code - don't go this way...

Comment: Sir, BLACK as such is equivalent to UNASIGNED_FIELD. Just different names.